# When finding the time complexity for a nested loop, do you consider the outer loop even when the inner loop stops running?

Tags: time-complexity

Consider this code:

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
{
    for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
    {
        sum++;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

I've always known that to find the time complexity is to find how many times the inner-loop will be executed. But in the above code, the inner loop will keep running until i reaches N. When i exceeds N, the inner loop no longer updates the value of sum. But the outer loop will keep on running to completion.

So since the inner loop keeps running until i reaches N, shouldn't the time complexity of this code be O(N^2)? The solutions say that the time complexity is O(N^3).

Answer (score 0):

O(n^3) is correct!

For each iteration of the outer loop `(i)`, the inner loop `(j)` will iterate N times, then it will exit the loop. The outer loop will increase `i=0` to `i=1` then execute the inner loop again (which iterates another N times), and will keep doing this until `i = N*N`. So you can say the inner loop iterates N times per outer-loop-iteration.

The outer loop starts at `i=0` and iterates N*N times.

If the inner loop loops N times each time the outer loop loops, and the outer loop iterates N*N times, the total number of iterations of the *inner* loop is:

```
 (# of inner iterations per outer iteration) * (# of outer iterations)
 = (N) * (N*N)
 = N^3
```

Comment: The inner loop doesn't iterate N times when `i > N`. Which makes your answer incorrect.